# PHP write in .txt on local machine using Xamp

Tags: php, xampp

I have form and i want the content from the inputs to be stored in .txt file.
I'm using xamp and apache is running

HTML:

```
<form action="add.php" method="POST">
<div class="input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" name="realname" class="id">
    <input type="password" name="mypassword" class="password">
</div>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['realname']) && isset($_POST['mypassword'])) {
    $data = $_POST['realname'] . '-' . $_POST['mypassword'] . "\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('/mydata.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
```

it says how many bytes had been stored but the .txt file stays empty. So i cant figure out whats the problem.
 I am noob in PHP so maybe i'm doing some stupid things?

Comment: `/mydata.txt` <- the slash in *NIX means root of filesystem, but Windows doesn't have such a thing. Put a dot before the slash or remove the slash.

Comment: Thanks!!! it works now

Answer (score 0):

You have to use $_POST['realname'] and $_POST['mypassword'], the same names defined in the form.

Comment: sorry, i'm using same name just made mistake in writting the question here

Comment: Look at @CharlotteDunois comment, that is the solution!